Specific data and applications from TWRP backup
I have an almost 2-year-old TWRP backup on my HDD drive.
I have changed my device in the meantime.
I'm wondering whether there is a way to extract WhatsApp data from that old device.
What I did was I extracted literally everything until I got to folder com.fmwhatsapp.
Now, as far as I know, I should be copying com.fmwhatsapp to data/data which I did.
The problem with that is the fact that FM WhatsApp just keeps crashing after that.

First of all, I'm wondering whether applications actually have all of their data kept under data/data.
Second of all, is there any way to prevent an application from crashing, so I can access a number or two that I lost in the meantime that is in my chat list?


Might be related: How to manually transfer entire Whatsapp installation to another device (the hard way) -> check the file permissions
